# How do I count the number of occurrences of a factor within another factor?

Tags: r, frequency

I am very new to R so please bear with me!

I have a dataset with moth species, names of people who recorded the moths (Recorders), the year in which they were recorded, etc.

I would like to create a new table in which I have the number of different moth recorders per year. So far I have managed to make a table that gives me the total recordings made per year, but it's not quite what I need.

Here is the code I have used, would anybody be able to offer amendments or perhaps alternative ways to go about this?

```r
#create table with number of moth recorders per year
library(plyr)
diversity <- ddply(mydata4, c("Year"), summarise,
                   N    = length(Recorder))

diversity
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide a snapshot of your dataset so that we can help.

Comment: Maybe `table(mydata4$Recorder)` hard to say without knowing what your data structure and desired output looks like.

Comment: Without a sample of your data, this is a best guess. First move to using the "dplyr" package and look at the `group_by()` function.  You propably want to `group_by("Year", "Recorder")` and then summarize by with `n()`.

Comment: Try using `length(unique(Recorder))`.

Comment: How about `aggregate(Recorder ~ Year, mydata4, length)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are new to R and actively learning by the sounds of it;  I'll give you a nudge in the right direction.  I've always found things stuck best when I've figured them out myself and don't want to rob you of that.

So: It sounds like what you want is to have a ***count*** of the ***distinct*** recorders ***grouped*** by year.  (Hint hint)

I suggest having a look at the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages ([for which there is a handy cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)) as they are very useful for this sort of manipulation of data frames.

Also, as you are just picking up R, another useful thing worth taking a look at (though not relevant to your immediate problem) is [the Tidyverse Code Style Guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/index.html).

---

For those looking to have the answer spelled out, see below.  Look away now if you want to figure it out yourself.

The original question states that there is a data set with the following properties:

- Moth Species
- Name of person who Recorded it
- Year the moth was Recorded in.

The code provided in the question was reported to produce a table of the total number of recordings made per year.  From this we can infer that the original table has one row per recording.

The question also refers to two specific columns: `Year` and `Recorder`.  From this information and the fact that the question mentioned the data set included moth species we can infer that the data set has at least three columns:

- Species
- Recorder
- Year

So, let's make up some sample data:

```r
mydata4 <- data.frame(
  Species = c("Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Green"),      
  Year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2018", "2018"),
  Recorder = c("Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice")
)
```

Now, as I mentioned above, we desire a count of distinct Recorders grouped by year... so:

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata4 %>% group_by(Year) %>% distinct(Recorder) %>% count()
```

We group by year, we make sure that the rows in each group are distinct by Recorder and finally we count the rows in each group, as by this point we have made sure that each group only has one row per Recorder who recorded at least one moth in that year.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Year [2]
  Year      n
  <fct> <int>
1 2018      1
2 2019      2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I took a look at the cheat sheet and got a rough idea of what I was doing to check against what you'd written below. Problem solved now!